# Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.2.4) x64-mingw32'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was first developing my RoR application in Windows. Now since I've been founding a few problems regarding some gems, SSH and stuff I decided to move to Linux. I am trying to initate the application, but It seems I am not able to.

When I do `bundle update rails` I got the following error:

```
Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.2.4) x64-mingw32' in the gems available on this
machine.
```

This is my tzinfo-data gem:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :jruby]
```

But I have already tried with this one too:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Any idea? Because when I just do `bundle install` I also got the following error:

```
You have requested:
  rails = 4.2.4

The bundle currently has rails locked at 4.2.4.
Try running `bundle update rails`
```

Update:

Gemfile content

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

gem 'devise'

gem 'bootstrap_form'


# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem "bcrypt-ruby", '~> 3.0.0'

gem 'google-api-client', '0.9'

gem 'letsrate'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.6'

gem 'filterrific'

#gem 'ratyrate'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you’ve installed Rails using bundler and rubygems, make sure you have the latest version in your Gemfile:

```
rails '4.2.4'
```

there is Gemfile.lock which locks the version. You delete that and run again bundle install. it will work.

```
bundle install
```

Comment: that is not the problem, rails '4.2.4' is on GemFile... I will update the question with my gemfile content

Comment: just try to run `bundle install`

Comment: bundle install error is also reported on the question but: You have requested:
  rails = 4.2.4

The bundle currently has rails locked at 4.2.4.
Try running `bundle update rails`

Comment: Yeah there is Gemfile.lock which locks the version. You delete that and run again bundle install. it can work.

Comment: Updated the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106114/discussion-between-mohammad-shahadat-hossain-and-heisenberg).

Comment: Deleting gemfile.lock, and running bundle install actually did help.

Comment: Use `bundle install` if you already have a project and need to download necessary files.

Answer (score 1):

1. Visit https://rubygems.org/gems
2. Search for your gem. Once found, copy the text from the box titled **GEMFILE**
3. Add the copied text in your `Gemfile` found inside your app
4. Run `bundle`from the console opened at the root of your app.

On successful installation of the gems your console will display the message:
`Bundle complete! xx Gemfile dependencies, xx gems now installed.`